What are the distinct mathematical formalisms of quantum mechanics?
Consider the physical theory called non-relativistic quantum mechanics. What are the distinct mathematical formalisms for this physical theory? That is, different mathematical frameworks for this physical theory which for each physical phenomena compute exactly equal predictions.
Here is an example of what I mean by a mathematical formalism of quantum mechanics In textbooks like Sakurai, the formalism used is the following:

Systems are represented by Hilbert spaces $\mathcal{H}$ with states as equivalence classes $\{\lvert \psi \rangle\} \in P(\mathcal{H})$.
Dynamics are goverened by the Schrödinger equation, which is a differential equation defined over $\mathcal{H}$.
Observables are linear operators $\hat{O}: \mathcal{H} \to \mathcal{H}$ that live in a particular algebra endowed with two multiplication operations (multiplication and a Lie bracket).


See: Styer DF, Balkin MS, Becker KM, Burns MR, Dudley CE, Forth ST, Gaumer JS, Kramer MA, Oertel DC, Park LH, Rinkoski MT. Nine formulations of quantum mechanics. American Journal of Physics. 2002 Mar 1;70(3):288-97.  (possible access via here ). The paper contains a multitude of references.

See e.g. the book The Formalisms of Quantum Mechanics by F. David.

I will give a brief list of the options that come to mind, but this is most likely incomplete. In all cases I'll assume we are dealing with finitely many degrees of freedom, so we don't get to field theory (which is more complicated).
In the cases in which they are applicable, all of the following approaches yield the same results (you need to make a specific choice of deformation product for deformation quantization). However, it might happen that some of them are more general than others.
1. Sakurai's Approach
You just mentioned this one, and I'm just writing it for the count. Notice it works both for the Heisenberg, Schrödinger, and interaction pictures, since they only correspond to different (but unitarily equivalent) Hilbert spaces.
2. Sakurai's Approach with Density Matrices
You can further develop Sakurai's approach by allowing states to be density matrices on the Hilbert space. This allows you to consider mixed states in addition to pure states.
3. Path Integrals
Path integral quantization is an approach that becomes really useful in field theory, but you can do regular quantum mechanics with it. In this case, states are essentially given by means of boundary conditions on your path integral and you use the path integral itself to compute expectation valuables of observables. It is interesting that many things end up being commutative in this approach, so you don't deal with operators, but you might need to have to deal with anticommuting numbers (Grassmann numbers).
4. Algebraic approach
The algebraic approach is really popular in the mathematical physics community when working with quantum fields, especially in curved spacetime. In this case, you understand that the operators form a *-algebra, which is a vector space generalizing the space of operators on a Hilbert space. States are defined as positive normalized linear functionals in this algebra, and they are naturally understood as being the functions that map an observable to its expectation value in that state. This approach is more general than Sakurai's approach with density matrices and can be used to recover it. Usually there are more algebraic states than there are density matrix states.
5. Wigner quasiprobability function
Wigner's quasiprobability distribution allows you to describe a quantum state as a quasiprobability distribution on the classical phase space ("quasi" refers to the fact it can achieve negative values). I don't know much about this formalism, but it essentially allows you to do quantum mechanics in a setting more similar to classical mechanics.

Oh, and this is definitely an incomplete list. There is pilot wave theory, geometric quantization, and other options I didn't mention because I know essentially nothing about them. I once watched a seminar years ago about a completely different formulation of QM that was particularly useful for some application in chemistry and it seemed really different, but I recall nothing about it. Long story short: there are many formulations

5 and 6 are identical.

@CosmasZachos Thanks for pointing it out. I don't know much about either of them. I deleted 6

There is also a Quantum Logic approach..Anyway, why do you restrict the discussion to "non-QFT"? I mean QFT is a quantum theory...are there any more mathematical structures employed in QFT?

@TobiasFünke QFT has some difficulties in some of these approaches depending on how rigorous you want to be (density matrices may not be defined, for example). But mainly I think I wanted to exclude axiomatic QFT of the list because I don't think it can be formulated for QM in general. Also, OPs post seemed to suggest they didn't care about QFT

@NíckolasAlves Thanks for the response. I agree, I've missed that OP explicitly asked for non-relativistic QM; this however includes non-relativistic QFT, but you are right that this might add only mathematical complications in the scope of the question.

@TobiasFünke I agree it includes non-relativistic QFT, but I assumed they weren't interested in this case (otherwise, it would be a bit weird to exclude relativistic QFT, in my opinion).
